# Trying to show multiple relationships with Drupal view

Tags: 7, views

I have a website with Car manufacturers (c_manufacturer), each Manufacturer has car Models (content type: c_model), and each model has picture (content type: model_pictures).

I'm trying to create a view to display on every Manufacturer's page and show the car pictures of the car models that belong to that Manufacturer. 
Using Contextual Filter for the Manufacturer node ID, I added 3 relationships: 
Content: c_manufacturer  - reverse 
Content: c_model  - reverse (Using Relationship: c_manufacturer)
Content: model_pictures  - reverse (Using Relationship: c_model)

I tried to show the Title field (something that all of the content types have on my site) 
and I keep getting no result on the view Preview (when giving a manufacturer ID as an argument), what am I missing ?

Comment: p.s. I tried to do it with 2 relationships too, ditching the c_manufacturer reverse, didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

I would have used [references](http://drupal.org/project/references) to start with.

You would create a manufacturer (e.g BMW). Now BMW will have a picture/logo description etc.

Then you would create a CAR (e.g 320i). Now the car will have all the fields you want and most importantly the reference to the manufacturer.

You will then need to create a block view of content type CAR.

**Fields** will be picture and title(320i).

**Filters** will be "Content: Type (=Car)".

**Contextual filters** will be "Content: Nid".

Then in Structure->blocks you move the newly created block view into the Content section under "Main page content".

When visiting the BMW node the view should display the car + title.